# Would you allow 4e races and classes into 5e games?

Tags: dnd-5e, dnd-4e, races

I have a person in my group that wants to be an insect-like 4e race in my campaign. I don't know if I should allow it, because it may disturb the party balance.

Comment: I'm voting to hold this question as opinion-based. The titular question would be off-topic here as a discussion prompt. However, if your *real* question is "will allowing [this race] (link it, if possible) into my 5e game imbalance things?" then I think that's totally answerable.

Comment: Oh, and welcome, happy gaming, take the [tour] when you get a chance, and know that [edit]ing your question will automatically put it in a queue to review it's hold-status, or you can flag it for direct attention. Cheers!

Comment: @nitsua60 It's unlikely there's a legal link to the 4e content mentioned (there's not really a 4e SRD or anything similar like there is for 3.x and 5e), but the name of the race (I assume it's the thri-kreen from the Dark Sun setting book) would be good to include.

Comment: Of interest would be the section in the DMG regarding how to "make" your own race. Perhaps that could be used to adapt this insect race, instead of allowing it "as is".

Comment: I believe you are talking the Thri-Kreen? The answer is no, allowing a non core game race into a game doesn't automatically unbalance the game, however the conversion has to be done in such a way as to create a balanced 5e version of the race. The D&D wiki has a homebrew section that has a [5e Thri-Kreen](https://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/Thri-Kreen_(5e_Race)) you could take a look at. I've used races from there before, and found them decently balanced. (never used this one before though)